# How can I join tuples to strings in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I am trying to join tuples in a column of my pandas dataframe and place that string in a new, separate column.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': ['001', '002', '003'],
                   'Tuple': [('hey', 'you'), ('you', 'can'), ('can', 'go')]})
```

I have tested the join using:

```
' '.join(_df.Tuple[0])
```

and the output looks like:

`'hey you'`;

however, when I attempt to extend this to the rest of the `Tuple` column in the data frame with:

```
df['String'] = ' '.join([entry for entry in df.Tuple])
```

I receive a type error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found`. When I look into this error, I see an example that works for lists but not for dataframes. How can I iterate through a dataframe, joining the tuples in each row and place those strings into a new column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because your list comprehension returns tuples which are immutable :

This `([entry for entry in df.Tuple])`

returns

```
[('hey', 'you'), ('you', 'can'), ('can', 'go')]
```

a simpler method would be to use aggregation method on each item within the tuple on a row level.

```
df['Tuple'].agg(' '.join)

out:
0    hey you
1    you can
2     can go
Name: Tuple, dtype: object
```

Comment: from OP method : `df.Tuple = [' '.join(entry) for entry in df.Tuple]` (as a note to OP)

Comment: This worked for my example dataframe, but got a new error on my actual dataframe saying `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. I cannot really share that one as proprietary, and not even sure how to duplicate error with a test dataframe. Appreciate your help and quick answer though!

Comment: add in `fillna(' ')` before or filter out NA rows @nellac77

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

`df['String'] = df['Tuple'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))`